# How can I import bs4 from Beautiful Soup in Python3 on OSX 10.12.5?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to fix what seems like a common problem with importing a module in Python 3. I'm running OS X 10.12.5 and have Python 3 installed on my MacBook Air and am using Sublime Text to edit and run my code.

When I try this import:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

...I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/<myname>/Python/code-python3/Pgm#001", line 5, in <module>
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
ImportError: No module named 'bs4'
```

I successfully installed with this PIP and on every re-install I see this:

```
$ pip install beautifulsoup4
Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4 in ./anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages
```

I've tried qualifying the location with things like:

```
from ./anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

...but invariably get a variety of syntax errors; usually on the first '/'.

I am not using a virtual environment but do plan to read up on that approach as these kind of configuration and setup errors are big time wasters.

When I try to run this right in python3 I get slightly different errors:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/<myname>/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/bs4/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from .builder import builder_registry, ParserRejectedMarkup
  File "/Users/<myname>/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/bs4/builder/__init__.py", line 314, in <module>
    from . import _html5lib
  File "/Users/<myname>/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/bs4/builder/_html5lib.py", line 70, in <module>
    class TreeBuilderForHtml5lib(html5lib.treebuilders._base.TreeBuilder):
AttributeError: module 'html5lib.treebuilders' has no attribute '_base'
```

Any tips about where the obvious answer exists that I am still missing would be greatly appreciated. I've seen a lot of things about PATH and PYTHONPATH in similar questions but had no success with any of these solutions either.

Comment: Did you try using conda instead of pip?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I'm not a fan of anaconda but looks like the path is being pointed to:

> "/Users//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages"

... and for the sake of keeping things as clean as possible (this being a good example/reason why you'll see people say to use env for your python projects)

Lets google here! Here's how to remove anaconda:

```
conda install anaconda-clean #first the configs
anaconda-clean --yes
rm -rf ~/anaconda.* #then conda, the ".*" is regex to cover any version
```

The check your bash_profile and/or bashrc; and here you can set your Python path. Make sure it not pointing to anaconda

if you run

```
ls -lh `which python # orpython3
```

You'll get the path of which is the one you'll be setting as the path.